# Create one VS solution for both debug and release config using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I'm working on CMake project in Windows, 
I have both configuration for Release and Debug, 
but I can't find how to config the release libraries to be linked in the release config at the Visual studio, and the debug libraries linked in the debug config.

Currently if I want work on the visual studio and move between the release and the debug I need to run the cmake again.

Any solution?

---

**For Example:**

```
set(MY_DEBUG_LIBRARY mylibd.lib)  
set(MY_RELEASE_LIBRARY mylib.lib)

add_executable(App main.cpp)  
target_link_libraries(App ${MY_DEBUG_LIBRARY/MY_RELEASE_LIBRARY})
```

---

things I already tried:

```
target_link_libraries(App debug ${MY_DEBUG_LIBRARY} optimized ${MY_RELEASE_LIBRARY})
```

put both libraries in all configurations.

```
target_link_libraries(App $< $< CONFIG:Debug>:${MY_DEBUG_LIBRARY}> $< $<  CONFIG:Release>:${MY_RELEASE_LIBRARY}>
```

also put both libraries in all configurations.

---

**I've found my problem**

I created my own Configuration instead of just using the default.
than using the first option I tried - work well.

thanks for the help!

Comment: With multi-configuration generators (Visual Studio & XCode), this should work just fine out of the box. Can you reduce your `CMakeLists.txt` to a [mcve] and post it?

Comment: Generally speaking with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) like `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:your-debug.lib> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:your-release.lib>` or [imported libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html?highlight=imported#imported-libraries)

Comment: I've used the commands you tried more often then I can think of and they definitely work in CMake with Visual Studio solutions. So we need more information like CMake, Visual Studio and OS versions. And the `cmake` call you use to configure/generate the build environment (best include the output of CMake).